# Javascript: Print multiple form inputs to a textarea

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I'm very new to javascript but I'm trying to create a simple program that makes formatting sources for the blog I edit very easy. I want the information that users type into the form to be printed out into one textarea. This is what I have so far:

```
<html>
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function writeCode() {
        var src1 = document.getElementById('src1').value,
            src2 = document.getElementById('src2').value,
            src3 = document.getElementById('src3').value,
        var lnk1 = document.getElementById('lnk1').value,
            lnk2 = document.getElementById('lnk2').value,
            lnk3 = document.getElementById('lnk3').value,
        outputValue = '<span style="color: #888888; font-size: xx-small;">Sources: </span>' + '<a href="' + lnk1 + '"target="_blank"><span style="color: #2200fc; font-size: xx-small;">' + src1 + '</span></a>'  + ', ' + '<a href="' + lnk2 + '"target="_blank"><span style="color: #2200fc; font-size: xx-small;">' + src2 + '</span></a>'
        document.getElementById('outputArea').value = outputValue;

        if (src3.length + lnk3.length != 0){
            outputValue2 = ', ' + '<a href="' + lnk3 + '"target="_blank"><span style="color: #2200fc; font-size: xx-small;">' + src3 + '</span></a>'
            document.getElementById('outputArea2').value = outputValue2;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('outputArea2').value = ' '
        }
    console.log(writeCode);
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="sources">
            Source 1 <input type="text" id="src1"/>
                Link 1 <input type="text" id="lnk1"/></br>
            Source 2 <input type="text" id="src2"/>
                Link 2 <input type="text" id="lnk2"/></br>
            Source 3 <input type="text" id="src3"/>
                Link 3 <input type="text" id="lnk3"/></br>
            <input type="button" value="Write my code!" onclick="writeCode();"/>
            <input type="button" value="Cite another article!" onClick="window.location.reload()"/></br>

            <textarea style="width:600px;height:100px;" name="outputForm">
                <p id="outputArea"></p>
                <p id="outputArea2"><p>
                <p id="outputArea3"></p>
            </textarea>
    </form>
</div>
 </body>
```

Now, I got it working with multiple textareas by assigning them each a separate ID. But my goal is to have all the inputs that have been entered print out in one area. I've also tried assigning the ID outputArea to the textarea, and then having them all print out to outputArea, but it returns an error like 'Cannot assign value null.' Any advice on how to go about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with this:

HTML:

```
<form name="sources">Source 1
    <input type="text" id="src1" />Link 1
    <input type="text" id="lnk1" />
    </br>Source 2
    <input type="text" id="src2" />Link 2
    <input type="text" id="lnk2" />
    </br>Source 3
    <input type="text" id="src3" />Link 3
    <input type="text" id="lnk3" />
    </br>
    <input type="button" value="Write my code!" onclick="writeCode();" />
    <input type="button" value="Cite another article!" onClick="window.location.reload()" />
    </br>
    <textarea style="width:600px;height:100px;" name="outputForm" id="outputForm">    </textarea>
</form>
```

JS:

```
function writeCode() {
    var src1 = document.getElementById('src1').value,
    src2 = document.getElementById('src2').value,
    src3 = document.getElementById('src3').value,
    lnk1 = document.getElementById('lnk1').value,
    lnk2 = document.getElementById('lnk2').value,
    lnk3 = document.getElementById('lnk3').value,
    outputValue = '<span style="color: #888888; font-size: xx-small;">Sources: </span>' + '<a href="' + lnk1 + '"target="_blank"><span style="color: #2200fc; font-size: xx-small;">' + src1 + '</span></a>' + ', ' + '<a href="' + lnk2 + '"target="_blank"><span style="color: #2200fc; font-size: xx-small;">' + src2 + '</span></a>';

    if (src3.length != 0 && lnk3.length != 0) {
        outputValue += ', ' + '<a href="' + lnk3 + '"target="_blank"><span style="color: #2200fc; font-size: xx-small;">' + src3 + '</span></a>';
    }
    document.getElementById('outputForm').value = outputValue;
}
```

You need to be careful with the errors being displayed in the console, there were a few which might not have been crashing the page but definitely causing issues with what you were attempting to do.

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/kRRBR/1/

Comment: Not a problem, glad I could help :)